# XMLHttpRequest event listeners order of execution

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have code retrieving some data using an `XMLHttpRequest` that looks something like this:

```
var myObject = new MyObject();
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.addEventListener("load", function () {
    myObject.data = req.responseText;
}, false);

req.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
    myObject.save();
}, false);

req.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/foo.txt", true);
req.send(null);
```

Basically, if the Ajax request succeeds, I want to save the data retrieved in `myObject`, and then regardless of the status of the Ajax request, I want to save `myObject` to the database.  So far it's worked as it's intended to, but I'm slightly uneasy about the order of execution of the `load` and `loadend` listeners.  The most I could find on this was from the [`XMLHttpRequest` living standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) (regarding `loadend`):

> After one of error, abort, timeout or load has been dispatched.

Does this guarantee that if the Ajax request succeeds, that the `load` listener will **finish** executing before the `loadend` listener **starts**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> order of execution of the `load` and `loadend` listeners

As you can judge from [the standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/), `loadend` will always be dispatched after `load` or the respective error event.

> Does this guarantee that if the Ajax request succeeds, that the `load` listener will finish executing before the `loadend` listener starts?

JavaScript is single-threaded, with a run-to-completion event loop. Two listeners will never run at the same time.

Comment: Thank you.  So do I understand it correctly that when an event (event 1) is "dispatched", all listeners for it are queued up and will fire one by one, all before the listeners for events dispatched after event 1?

Comment: @user3250365: Yes, they are always fired one by one. See also [firing an event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire) and [dispatching events](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch). In this case, it seems that not even an event queue is involved.